# How get all validation errors in DOMDocument.Validate at once?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, domdocument

It seems like DOMDocument.Validate stops at the first error and does not show the rest of the errors in the xml file.

So I use my schema MiniSchema.xsd:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:lhd="http://www.statistik.gv.at/LHD-V55/Schema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.statistik.gv.at/LHD-V55/Schema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="kennsatz"> 
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="finanzjahr" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and my xml file ErrorTwice.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lhd:kennsatz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:lhd="http://www.statistik.gv.at/LHD-V55/Schema"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.statistik.gv.at/LHD-V55/Schema file:///C:/Temp/MiniSchema.xsd">
                <lhd:finanzjahr>gogo</lhd:finanzjahr>
                <schnuppl>Error1</schnuppl>
                <schalbaschlabadu>Error2</schalbaschlabadu>
</lhd:kennsatz>
```

As you can see ErrorTwice.xml has two errors inside. The element "schnuppl" and the element "schalbaschlabadu" are not allowed.

When I use the following code:

```
Dim objSchemaCache
Set objSchemaCache = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.6.0")

objSchemaCache.Add "http://www.statistik.gv.at/LHD-V55/Schema", "C:\Temp\MiniSchema.xsd"

Dim docum
Set docum = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Call docum.Load("C:\Temp\ErrorTwice.xml")
Set docum.Schemas = objSchemaCache
Dim dParseError

Set dParseError = docum.validate()
Stop
If dParseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Fehler " & dParseError.ErrorCode & ": '" & dParseError.Reason & "' bei XML-Validierung. ")
Else
    Call MsgBox("No Error")
End If
```

There is only one error returned: "schnuppl is not valid". But then the validation stops and until I fix this error I will never know about the other error in the file ("schalbaschlabadu" is not valid).

In the real world this is a problem, because the creation of the real xml (bigreal.xml) takes quite a while. So my customers: create the xml - check it - get an error - create the xml - check it - get another error - create the xml once again - check it - get another error - ...

As the "XML Tools"-AddOn of notepad ++ is able to find both errors in ErrorTwice.xml at once I think there is a way.

So how to get all the validation errors at once?

Comment: See my answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575887/even-with-errorhandler-why-is-schema-validation-ending-after-the-first-error/58666557?noredirect=1#comment103660279_58666557

Comment: @kimbert: "XML Tools" addon of notepad ++ is able to find both errors at once. So this is possible. I edited my question in this way.