# Capture all XML validation errors during validate the XML file against XSD file in java

Tags: java

I am using jdk1.8 javax xml validation api to validate the XML file against the corresponding XSD. The requirement is to capture all XML validation errors against the XSD in the given xml file during the validation.

But now validation will stop during the first occurrence of the invalid element or validation error in the given XML file, even though have set the error handler (without throwing the any exception ) in the Validator API. Below is the code snippet. I am using the JDK v1.8  to validate the XML file.

```
     String xsd=
     String xml=
        try {
           
            SchemaFactory  schemaFactory = 
           SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsd)));
           
            Validator  validator = schema.newValidator();
            
            errorHandler=new XMLSchemaValidationErrorHandler(validator);
            validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
            StringWriter  writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult  result = new StreamResult(writer);
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), result);
            
        } catch (SAXException e) {
           
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
           
        } catch (IOException err) {
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }
    }
    
package com.xml.validation.utils;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

   public class XMLSchemaValidationErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{

    private static Logger LOGGER = 
   LoggerFactory.getLogger(XMLSchemaValidationErrorHandler.class);
    
    final List<SAXParseException> exceptions=new LinkedList<SAXParseException>();
    private Validator validator;
     public XMLSchemaValidationErrorHandler(Validator v) {
          super();
          validator = v;
         }
     
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
     
        LOGGER.error("warning SAXParseException :::"+exception.getMessage());
        exceptions.add(exception);  
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        LOGGER.error("error SAXParseException Message :::  "+exception.getMessage());
        exceptions.add(exception);  
        
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        LOGGER.error("fatalError SAXParseException ::: "+exception.getMessage());
        exceptions.add(exception);  
        
    }

    public List<SAXParseException> getExceptions() {
        return exceptions;
    }

}
```

Comment: Technically speaking, it is very hard to find errors after the first one, simply because the error might be so strong as to leave the parser not knowing what it should expect. For example, violating a cardinality restriction (producing a tag twice when a single occurence is allowed), is pretty much OK to recover from. But closing the root tag unexpectedly in the middle of the document, how would you recover from that ? What would be the error after, seeing you are out of the document anyway? I'd be surprised if you find a library that adresses it. Happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @Rajashekhar

Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575887/even-with-errorhandler-why-is-schema-validation-ending-after-the-first-error